# How to display a NSMenu with a search box to limit the number of results (similar to Xcode menus)

Tags: search, nsmenu

This kind of menus are available in Xcode when searching for a function name (see attached image):
[image]

Is it a standard NSMenu with a customized item?

Is it a fully customized NSWindow, with customs NSViews?

Is there an open-source library that can offer such function?

Any advices to implement such menu?

Comment: I need to do the same thing, any idea?